# ImportError: cannot import name CertificateError

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below code throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_PAN_traffic_scraper.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError
ImportError: cannot import name CertificateError
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to browse to the firewall portal interface which uses a self-signed certfificate and throws a certificate error when attempting to browse to the site using a specific API URL and API key. Ultimately, I want to expand the code to parse through the XML to look for specific tags and attributes (source / destination / ports / etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ssl
import urllib
import urllib3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

DAL = "1.1.1.1"
CHI = "2.2.2.2"

firewall_ip = [ 'Dallas', 'Chicago' ]

datacenter=raw_input('Which firewall do you want traffic logs for? \"DAL\" or \"CHI\"?: ')

contents = ""

cmd = "/api/?type=log&log-type=traffic&query=(receive_time geq '2017/1/22 23:00:00')"
key = "&key=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa="
url = "https://"+pan_ip[0]+urllib3.urlencode(cmd)+key

response = urllib3.urlopen(url, verify=False)
contents = ET.fromstring(response.read())


if DC is "DAL":
    print contents
else:
    print "Goodbye"

#result = ""



#for i in contents[0][0]:
    #   if i[0][0].tag == entry:
    #       for j in i[0][0]:
    #           if j.tag == 'src' and j.text == src:
    #               result = i.attrib['name']
    #print result
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what debugging steps you have tried so far?and add that to the question!

Comment: `CertificateError` does exist in the standard `ssl` module. You wouldn't happen to have a file named `ssl.py` or a module folder named `ssl` in your path that is being imported instead of the standard one, right?

Comment: Harshdeep - I haven't tried any specific debugging steps. If you have anything you would like to recommend, I would be willing to try.

slezica - I checked 'env' in my terminal window and do not see anything like you described. everything is standard as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does `env python -c 'import ssl; print dir(ssl)'` include a `CertificateError` in the output somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled urllib3 and did a fresh install:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/shazow/urllib3.git
cd to the folder containing urllib3/
$ python setup.py install
```

This got rid of the error completely.